# How to loop through foreach inside another foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Im trying to get day  and amount of rental to be displayed according to car name. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

here's my code:

```
if(isset($q)) {
    mysql_select_db($database);
    /*$query_showmake = "SELECT carName FROM car_name WHERE carMake_id='$q'";*/
    $query_showmake = "SELECT car_name.carName_id, car_name.carName, car_name.carMake_id, gallery, gallery_id, gallery.gallery, gallery.carName_id, car_make.carMake_id  FROM car_name, gallery, car_make WHERE car_name.carName_id = gallery.carName_id AND car_name.carMake_id = '$q' AND car_name.carMake_id = car_make.carMake_id";

    $result_showmake = mysql_query($query_showmake)or die(mysql_error());
    while($row_showmake = mysql_fetch_array($result_showmake)) {
        $carMake_show = $row_showmake['carName'];
        $carmake[$row['carName_id']][]=$row_showmake;
        /* echo $carMake_show.'<br/>';*/
    }
    ?>

    <table border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">

    <?php
    foreach($carmake as $make=>$name) {
        foreach($name as $n) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td class='carname'>".$n{'carName'}.'</td><td rowspan="2" valign="top" class="cardetail">Car Details</td></tr>';
            /*echo $n{'carMake_id'}.'<br/>';
            echo $n{'gallery'}.'<br/>';*/
            echo"<tr><td class='img'><img src='management/uploads/{$n['carMake_id']}/{$n['gallery']}' width='400' height='200'>";
            echo "</td></tr>";
            echo"<tr><td colspan='2' class='days'>Days : ";

            echo "</td></tr>";

            echo"<tr><td colspan='2' class='days'>Amount : ";

            echo "</td></tr>";
            echo"<tr><td height='50' colspan='2'></td></tr>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    </table>
<?php
}
```

// I have inserted rental info only for one car name. And i inserted the day and amount of rental separately instead of at one go.

So when the query is executed, the day and amount info loops for three times as i inserted three data for the car like day 1=RM 50,day7= RM 650 and day30=RM 2000.

**But all I want is to be able to loop through only the day and amount for a car name  and display like this:**

carname1
image for carname 1
day 1 , 2, 3
amount 1, 2, 3

**instead of**

carname1
image for carname 1
day 1
amount 1

carname1
image for carname 1
day 1 , 2
amount 1, 2

carname1
image for carname 1
day 1 , 2, 3
amount 1, 2, 3

Comment: What does the `$carmake` array look like?

Comment: @mistermansam  that is for car brands..i call the car names here according to carmake_id